# Find authorized application/revoke OAuth tokens of a user WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using a custom datastore with the WSO2 Identity Server to authenticate users stored in an RDBMS. The userstore is on readOnly mode.

How the users are added/deleted from the RDBMS is unknown to the identity server.

This is the use case:

"An external application should allow users to login using credentials stored in the RDBMS and retrieve a token that can be used to communicate with the resource provider. The application will use authorization_code grant for this.

After a successful authorization the client will receive a JWT token which will be used when trying to contact the resource provider.

The resource provider uses the introspection endpoint of the identity server to confirm that the token is valid before proceeding with the request."

This flow is working as expected. A user can login and access the resources as expected.

However two issues arise:

1. Can I somehow retrieve the applications that a user has authorized from the Identity server? I am aware of the dashboard but I want to move that functionality in another app.
2. If a user is deleted from the RDBMS any active OAuth tokens issued for him are not revoked from the identity server and the user can still access the resource. I do not want to force the resource owner to check if the user is still valid.

From my understanding those actions should be supported from the Identity server with no additional products. Admin services are enabled on the Identity Server but I can't locate the wsdl & endpoint to do that.

I am using WSO2 IS 5.8

Comment: If you have enabled admin services, you can start the server with `-DosgiConsole` and when the server is started, hit the enter/return key several times to get the OSGI shell in the console. In the OSGI shell, type: osgi> listAdminServices. Then a list of all available admin services will be listed. To see the service contract of an admin service, select the admin service's URL and then paste it in your browser with ?wsdl at the end.

Answer (score 0):

For 1, you can use the [1] admin service to get the application information. If you have enabled the wsdl discovery, you can get the wsdl from `https://<carbon_host>:9443/services/<service_name>?wsdl.`

For 2, This is not possible as you are doing a direct modification to the DB. If it go through the IS then there are event listeners which will trigger after the deletion and revoke all the necessary tokens. If you need to achieve this, then you may have to write a hook in the DB side and at the deletion you may need to revoke all the related tokens by calling the revoke endpoint.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Using+the+Service+Provider+API

Comment: For #1 I do not want to get the application info, I want to find out what apps has a given user given authorization for. Suppose I am user XYZ and I have granted access to my data to applications X and application Y. In the dashboard I can see that I have authorized the applications, is there any way to access that information through the identity server?

For #2 The application responsible for the deletion of the user doesn't know the tokens, it relies on the IS for that. I can't revoke a token I don't know that exists.

Comment: #1 it should be possible. Because dashboard is also calling admin services to achieve this. So if dashboard can do it, there should be an admin service.
#2 Then you have to delete the user through IS. Otherwise there is no way of triggering the event listeners to clear the tokens.

Comment: I am afraid I can't do a user deletion through my userstore. Trying that ends up with an error `InvalidOperation Invalid operation. User store is read only` I believe there must be another way to achieve that.